# How to change font properties in PowerShell 5?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

I want to make the font as bold for the path that I'm printing using `Write-Host`. I'm flexible to using other methods like echo or something else.

I've tried other methods like `Write-Debug`, etc, also checked the module `WindowsConsoleFonts`.
But none of them supports font properties like making them bold or italic while printing them.

```
$pathString = "[" + (Get-Location) + "]"
Write-Host $pathString -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

I'm using PowerShell 5.1 which doesn't support MarkDown rendering, else I would have done it using Markdown.

Comment: This is not due to a lack of available modules out there - the windows console host doesn't support variable fonts for individual characters or words, so what you're asking for is likely impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can achieve *bold* text** via [VT (Virtual Terminal) escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

However, **regular Windows console windows (`conhost.exe`) do *not* support *italics***, and **neither does their upcoming successor, [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)** (at least as of this writing).<sup>[1]</sup>

In recent versions of Windows 10, support for VT sequences is enabled by default in both *Windows PowerShell* and PowerShell *Core*.

However, `Write-Host` has no support for them, so you must embed the escape sequences directly into the strings you pass to `Write-Host` (or strings you send to the success output stream, if it goes to the console):

Note:

- I'm omitting `Write-Host` from the examples below, because it isn't strictly necessary, but colored text generally should indeed be written to the display (host), not to the success output stream.
- While it is better to consistently use VT sequences for all formatting needs - including colors - it is possible to combine them with `Write-Host -ForegroundColor /`-BackgroundColor`.

**PowerShell *Core***:

PowerShell Core supports embedding escape sequences *directly* in `"..."` (double-quoted strings), via the `` `e `` escape sequence, which expands to a literal ESC character, which is the character that *initiates* a VT escape sequence.

```
"To `e[1mboldly`e[m go ..., in `e[36mcyan`e[m."
```

**Windows PowerShell**:

There's no support for `` `e ``; the easiest solution is to use `\e` as  placeholders and use `-replace` to substitute actual ESC characters (Unicode code point `0x1b`) for them:

```
"To \e[1mboldly\e[m go ..., in \e[36mcyan\e[m." -replace '\\e', [char] 0x1b
```

---

<sup>[1] From PowerShell *Core*, you can run the following test command to see if the word `italics` prints in italics: 
`` "`e[3mitalics`e[m after" ``

Note that italics in the terminal *are* supported on **macOS** and at least in some **Linux** distros; e.g., Ubuntu 18.04</sup>

Comment: Doesn't really do what I wanted, but I believe there's no solution to it. I think this is the next best thing we can do in powershell, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @kr9s8n1. So you were looking for italics as well, and possibly additional formatting? Or is it primarily the aspect of having to embed escape sequences that is the problem?

Comment: Yep, I was looking for some additional formatting including italics, and it helped me look in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Some built-in ANSI text formatting sequences were added in PowerShell 7.2 (PSCore). They are accessible via the `$PSStyle` variable/object. More documentation can be found at [about_ANSI_Terminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals#psstyle) (Microsoft link).

Try entering `$PSStyle.Formatting`, `$PSStyle.Foreground`, `$PSStyle.Background` (or simply `$PSStyle`) at a PowerShell prompt for a list of some supported styles and formatters.

#### Example (Bold)

```
Write-Host "hello $($PSStyle.bold)bold$($PSStyle.BoldOff) world"
```

[image]

#### Example (Foreground colors)

```
$PSStyle.Foreground
```

[image]